# Method return value in write context error

Tags: php

I am currently learning the basics of MVC. I am running into a php fatal error with the code below. The error states 
`Can't use method return value in write context`. How can I fix this?

```
    $module = empty( $uri->fragment(0) ) ? 'index' : $uri->fragment(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `empty()` is a language construct and until recently it only allowed variable references as its argument, whereas your code passes a return value (which is not a reference).

Fortunately, because a return value wouldn't be undefined or non-existent, you can use a shortened [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$module = $uri->fragment(0) ?: 'index';
```

Before 5.3 you would have to use the longer version:

```
$module = $uri->fragment(0) ? $uri->fragment(0) : 'index';
```

Answer (score 0):

You've come across one of the many little quirks of PHP :).

Prior to PHP 5.5, `empty` works only on variables (more info on the [manual page](http://php.net/empty)). This means you need to first assign `$url->fragment(0)` to something:

```
$fragment = $uri->fragment(0);
$module = empty($fragment) ? 'index' : $fragment;
```

Since existence isn't an issue, you don't actually need empty here (since `empty($var)` is equivalent to `isset($var) && $var`):

```
$module = $uri->fragment(0) ? $uri->fragment(0) : 'index';
```

---

In this situation it won't matter, but as a general piece of advice, be careful using `empty` with strings. It can have a few "wtf?" moments in corner cases. For example, all forms of `0` are considered empty (`0`, `"0"`, `0.0`).